# program crashing while bubble sorting?

Tags: c++, string, bubble-sort

```
            int sortAtt2,compare=0,counter=0;
            string tempTitle;
            for(int t=0; t<MAX_BOOKS; t++)
            {
                for(int i=0; i<MAX_BOOKS; i++)
                {
                    compare=(books[i+1].bookTitle).compare(books[i].bookTitle);
                    if(compare>0)
                    {
                        tempTitle=books[i].bookTitle;
                        books[i].bookTitle=books[i+1].bookTitle;
                        books[i+1].bookTitle=tempTitle;

                    }
                }
            }
```

this is my code, whenever I execute this function, the program crashes. Any idea why? I am comparing two strings here to bubble sort them.

Comment: Where exactly does it crash? You should run the program in a debugger, that will tell you the crash location. Usually this helps finding the problem.

Comment: @sth I just found that it crashes at the string compare argument.

Comment: I don't meant to burst your bubble, but...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Out-of bounds access. You are accessing `books[i+1]` in a loop where `i` counts up to `MAX_BOOKS - 1`, i,e, you are accessing `books[MAX_BOOKS]` - one past the end of an array with `MAX_BOOKS` elements.

Comment: but the same exact argument works for integers, just that it doesnt work with strings :(

Comment: @JoshuaJones It's still wrong though, no matter whether you use strings or ints or whatever. You were just lucky/unlucky that it worked with `int`s. Accessing out of bounds is *undefined behaviour*, which means that it may work, not work, or steal your truck and run over your mailbox.

Comment: @JoshuaJones - Primarily because you wouldn't be calling methods on `float` and `int` types. The value returned would be whatever is in memory after your array.

Comment: @Aesthete It's important to mention though that this is by no means guaranteed. The byte after your array may be in a read-protected region for example, in which case it would crash even for `int` arrays.

Comment: @Aesthete: in general, and assuming that the memory is even writable in both cases, it's more dangerous to try to do things to an uninitialised `std::string` than an uninitialised `int`: for the string there are pointers to what will be presumed to be heap-allocated memory, following those pointers will almost certainly fail.  For the int, everything's at least self-contained.  Undefined behaviour either way - but it's because of things like this that the "but it worked for `int`s" logic isn't a good sanity check.

Comment: @TonyD - Yep. Maybe you should address the OP though, because it seems he needs the lesson in memory management.

Comment: Aesthete: ah yes - sorry! And a +1 for you below.  @JoshuaJones: please take note ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you have MAX_BOOKS of 8.

```
Book books[MAX_BOOKS];
```

And you loop like this.

```
for(int i=0; i<MAX_BOOKS; i++)
{
  books[i+1];
}
```

What happens when `i == 7`?

Comment: but the same exact argument works for integers and floats, just not with strings.

Comment: That's because a `float` and an `int` doesn't have a `.bookTitle` method. Accessing those type will just return whatever is in the memory after your array.